# Laravel 5 : how to acces in a field on the hasMany table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have two models linked with hasMany to many relationship and there are my tables structure

```
clients = id|title...etc
roles = id|title...etc
client_role = id|client_id|role_id|desc
```

everythings works great 
now i want to access to the desc field on the client_role table how can i do that?
i tried

```
$client =  Client::first()->roles()->desc 
//nothing returned!
$client =  Client::first()->desc
```

but nothing ! please help

Comment: Post your model code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the columns of your pivot in the model relationship (Clients, for example):

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('desc');
```

Then you can call the column in the pivot like this:

```
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    echo $client->pivot->desc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Clients` model have:

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Clients');
}
```

In your `Roles` model have:

```
public function clients() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles');
}
```

Then from your controller:

```
$client =  Client::with('roles')->first();
dd($client->roles); // Laravel Collection
```